# Adding template path Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I Have been reading about templates in the django book, the author has suggested to add template path in the setting.py variable `TEMPLATE_DIRS`  but my setting.py has no `TEMPLATE_DIRS'(I understand why is it so)and I could find the below

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ’templates’).replace(’\\’,’/] #1
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

1)Does the above change I have madein the settings.py lead to me in the correct direction or is there any better way to do it? I wanna make myself sure before I put my self into others and end up in mess.

Answer (score 3):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable is deprecated since Django 1.8 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-dirs).

Your setup is fine, but you can clean it up a bit, for example:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'some_other_dir'),
            # other paths
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```